# In R how to split text/paragraph at end of statement (full stop) but not at the .(dot) in between the sentences

Tags: r, regex, text, nlp, csv

In R :-
For example:-

```
text_data<-" I have been a Gig subscriber for a decent amount of time.  When the service was originally installed I would observe 900+Mbps speeds.  I have deployed to Kosovo and since then (about 8 months ago) my wife has told me that the internet has become Slow.I consistently avg less than 286 Mbps when utilizing both speedtest.xfinity.com and fast.com as well as speedtest.net Current hardware: 1) Motorola MB8600 Modem 2) Linksys EA9500 I have not had a technician out to the site.Troubleshooting:I have replaced the Coax cable from wall to modem with 2 different new coax cables. I have replaced the ethernet from Modem to Router with 2 different new ethernet cables I have rebooted my Modem as well as attempted a factory reset. I have connected my home PC directly to the Modem (bypass router) with 2 different ethernet cables*NOTE*Wether I use the EA9500 or go directly to the PC I get the same slow speeds.*NOTE 2*I do not have a cable subscrption. No splitters on the line. It goes from Pole ---> Wall Jack --> Modem.There is always significant Uncorrected errors.  Attached are the Upstream and Downstream information and error logs.  These are 4 days after a modem reset."

> textdata<- as.String(text_data)

> a<-strsplit(text_data,".", fixed = TRUE)
```

**Output**:-

```
> a
[[1]]
 [1] " I have been a Gig subscriber for a decent amount of time"                                                                                                                           
 [2] "  When the service was originally installed I would observe 900+Mbps speeds"                                                                                                         
 [3] "  I have deployed to Kosovo and since then (about 8 months ago) my wife has told me that the internet has become Slow"                                                               
 [4] "I consistently avg less than 286 Mbps when utilizing both speedtest"                                                                                                                 
 [5] "xfinity"                                                                                                                                                                             
 [6] "com and fast"                                                                                                                                                                        
 [7] "com as well as speedtest"                                                                                                                                                            
 [8] "net Current hardware: 1) Motorola MB8600 Modem 2) Linksys EA9500 I have not had a technician out to the site"                                                                        
 [9] "Troubleshooting:I have replaced the Coax cable from wall to modem with 2 different new coax cables"                                                                                  
[10] " I have replaced the ethernet from Modem to Router with 2 different new ethernet cables I have rebooted my Modem as well as attempted a factory reset"                               
[11] " I have connected my home PC directly to the Modem (bypass router) with 2 different ethernet cables*NOTE*Wether I use the EA9500 or go directly to the PC I get the same slow speeds"
[12] "*NOTE 2*I do not have a cable subscrption"                                                                                                                                           
[13] " No splitters on the line"                                                                                                                                                           
[14] " It goes from Pole ---> Wall Jack --> Modem"                                                                                                                                         
[15] "There is always significant Uncorrected errors"                                                                                                                                      
[16] "  Attached are the Upstream and Downstream information and error logs"                                                                                                               
[17] "  These are 4 days after a modem reset"
```

**Desired Output in R:-**
**The text should split at end of statement(full stop) not at the .(dot) in between the sentences.)**

```
1)I have been a Gig subscriber for a decent amount of time.  
When the service was originally installed I would observe 900+Mbps speeds.  
2)I have deployed to Kosovo and since then (about 8 months ago) my wife has told me that the internet has become Slow.
3)I consistently avg less than 286 Mbps when utilizing both speedtest.xfinity.com and fast.com as well as speedtest.net Current hardware: 1) Motorola MB8600 Modem 2) Linksys EA9500 I have not had a technician out to the site.
4)Troubleshooting:I have replaced the Coax cable from wall to modem with 2 different new coax cables. 
5) I have replaced the ethernet from Modem to Router with 2 different new ethernet cables I have rebooted my Modem as well as attempted a factory reset. 
6)I have connected my home PC directly to the Modem (bypass router) with 2 different ethernet cables*NOTE*Wether I use the EA9500 or go directly to the PC I get the same slow speeds.
7)*NOTE 2*I do not have a cable subscrption. 
8)No splitters on the line. 
9)It goes from Pole ---> Wall Jack --> Modem.
10)There is always significant Uncorrected errors.  
11)Attached are the Upstream and Downstream information and error logs.  
12)These are 4 days after a modem reset.
```

Please assist.

Comment: The question is not clear. What's the difference between a dot at the end of a sentence and *between* sentences? Between sentences there is, by definition, a dot or other marker, that's how we know they are two sentences, not just one.

Comment: every statement in the paragraph should split at the end of it i.e. at the delimiter full stop (.) but for example if the statement has speedtest.xfinity.com in between the text  it should remain as it is.

Comment: Only initial thought, but you could get an approximate solution by splitting on `". "` as most sentences are separated by a period and a space, but domain names and numbers do not have a period followed by a space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit with working pattern for this particular data; you can split on a `.` followed by a space or a capital letter with pattern `\\.(?=( |[A-Z]))`.

You need to be careful because you have sentences that do not have the correct space after them. This makes it impossible to distinguish them reliably (see the third split sentence in output). This at least will not split on cases of `.com` as your first attempt does. Here, we use the capital letter difference to distinguish between `speedtest.xfinity.com` and `Slow.I` or `site.Troubleshooting`, but it won't hold if someone forgets the space and forgets to capitalise the next sentence.

```r
library(stringr)
text_data <- " I have been a Gig subscriber for a decent amount of time. When the service was originally installed I would observe 900+Mbps speeds. I have deployed to Kosovo and since then (about 8 months ago) my wife has told me that the internet has become Slow.I consistently avg less than 286 Mbps when utilizing both speedtest.xfinity.com and fast.com as well as speedtest.net Current hardware: 1) Motorola MB8600 Modem 2) Linksys EA9500 I have not had a technician out to the site.Troubleshooting:I have replaced the Coax cable from wall to modem with 2 different new coax cables. I have replaced the ethernet from Modem to Router with 2 different new ethernet cables I have rebooted my Modem as well as attempted a factory reset. I have connected my home PC directly to the Modem (bypass router) with 2 different ethernet cablesNOTEWether I use the EA9500 or go directly to the PC I get the same slow speeds.*NOTE 2*I do not have a cable subscrption. No splitters on the line. It goes from Pole ---> Wall Jack --> Modem.There is always significant Uncorrected errors. Attached are the Upstream and Downstream information and error logs. These are 4 days after a modem reset."
text_data %>%
  str_split("\\.(?=( |[A-Z]))")
#> [[1]]
#>  [1] " I have been a Gig subscriber for a decent amount of time"                                                                                                                                                                     
#>  [2] " When the service was originally installed I would observe 900+Mbps speeds"                                                                                                                                                    
#>  [3] " I have deployed to Kosovo and since then (about 8 months ago) my wife has told me that the internet has become Slow"                                                                                                          
#>  [4] "I consistently avg less than 286 Mbps when utilizing both speedtest.xfinity.com and fast.com as well as speedtest.net Current hardware: 1) Motorola MB8600 Modem 2) Linksys EA9500 I have not had a technician out to the site"
#>  [5] "Troubleshooting:I have replaced the Coax cable from wall to modem with 2 different new coax cables"                                                                                                                            
#>  [6] " I have replaced the ethernet from Modem to Router with 2 different new ethernet cables I have rebooted my Modem as well as attempted a factory reset"                                                                         
#>  [7] " I have connected my home PC directly to the Modem (bypass router) with 2 different ethernet cablesNOTEWether I use the EA9500 or go directly to the PC I get the same slow speeds.*NOTE 2*I do not have a cable subscrption"  
#>  [8] " No splitters on the line"                                                                                                                                                                                                     
#>  [9] " It goes from Pole ---> Wall Jack --> Modem"                                                                                                                                                                                   
#> [10] "There is always significant Uncorrected errors"                                                                                                                                                                                
#> [11] " Attached are the Upstream and Downstream information and error logs"                                                                                                                                                          
#> [12] " These are 4 days after a modem reset."
```

Created on 2018-08-12 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Thank you so much  for your prompt answer it worked for me and for the third line in which there is no space after . (full stop) , ideally there should space , have entered the space and it worked as desired .